# Transactions in php function or in mysql stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

What is better way to begin a transaction?
Inside procedures or PHP functions?

For example I calling MySQL procedure like this:

```
function sendLeaguesToDb(){ 
    $leagues = "";
    try{
        $this->PDO->beginTransaction();
        $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("call insupd_Leagues(:id,:name,:country,:sport_id,:his_data,:fixtures,:livescore,
        :numofmatches,:latestmatch)");
        $leagues=$this->soccer->GetAllLeagues();
        foreach($leagues as $key=>$value){
           $stmt->bindParam(':id',$value->Id);
           $stmt->bindParam(':name',$value->Name);  
           $stmt->bindParam(':country',$value->Country);
           $stmt->bindParam(':sport_id',$value->Sport_Id);
           $stmt->bindParam(':his_data',$value->Historical_Data);
           $stmt->bindParam(':fixtures',$value->Fixtures);
           $stmt->bindParam(':livescore',$value->Livescore);
           $stmt->bindParam(':numofmatches',$value->NumberOfMatches);
           $stmt->bindParam(':latestmatch',$value->LatestMatch);
           $stmt->execute();
           $this->PDO->commit();
        }
    }
    catch(XMLSoccerException $e){
        echo "XMLSoccerException: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "PDOException: ".$e->getMessage();
        $this->PDO->rollback();
    }
}
```

Is this good way if I want to send/get data fastest possible every minute/hour?

Comment: This is something you can easily benchmark yourself.

Comment: Whay you mean exactly?

Comment: @user1814358: you can do two different files containing that code, which runs the code for example 10000 times, and then you just time which one runs longer, and you get your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you want to see all the inserts as an 'atomic operation' you are doing right, as if one call to the SP fails, the rollback will undo all the changes made from the previous calls

If, otherwise, you want to "isolate" every single SP call, assuring that if it succedes the results are stored in the DB, you have to start and end the transaction inside the SP

I think the preferred solution is the first

**EDIT:** one thing i'm noting now: the commit should be after the for :

```
try{
    $this->PDO->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("call insupd_Leagues(:id,:name,:country,:sport_id,:his_data,:fixtures,:livescore,
    :numofmatches,:latestmatch)");
    $leagues=$this->soccer->GetAllLeagues();
    foreach($leagues as $key=>$value){
       $stmt->bindParam(':id',$value->Id);
       $stmt->bindParam(':name',$value->Name);  
       $stmt->bindParam(':country',$value->Country);
       $stmt->bindParam(':sport_id',$value->Sport_Id);
       $stmt->bindParam(':his_data',$value->Historical_Data);
       $stmt->bindParam(':fixtures',$value->Fixtures);
       $stmt->bindParam(':livescore',$value->Livescore);
       $stmt->bindParam(':numofmatches',$value->NumberOfMatches);
       $stmt->bindParam(':latestmatch',$value->LatestMatch);
       $stmt->execute();

    }    
   //move your commit here   
   $this->PDO->commit();

}
```

Comment: So it is better in my case to leave like this. Thanks.

Comment: I dont know why is commit inside foreach, i know that it should be out... :O
Thanks...